# Finding repetitions in big data sets

Tags: c#, algorithm, matlab, sequence, data-mining

I have a data set with data about failures in a control system. These data have following structure:

```
TYPE OF FAILURE (string), START DATE (dd/mm/yyyy), START TIME (hh/mm/ss), DURATION (ss), LOCALIZATION (string), WORKING TEAM (A,B,C), SHIFT (morning, afternoon, night)
```

The table with data has 555000 rows. 
First, I would like to analyze if there are repetitive failure sequences with respect to the START DATE parameter. Basicly, I would like to find something like this:

Failure 1 emerged on March 10. Failure 2 emerged on March 15. There is 5 days between them. Then Failure 1 emerged on April 10 and April 15, where are also 5 days between them. Than Failure 1 emerged on May 10 and May 15 also with 5 days between them. However Failure 1 could emerged also on different dates, but for me it is interesting to know, that there is stronger possibility, that Failure 2 will emerge 5 days after Failure 1 and that between these events (F1->F2) is one month.

I don't know if my explanation is clear enough. However I am searching for suitable methods / algorithms with which I will be able to extract such sequences from the data describet above. Can you please point me to some methods? Or simply let's brainstorm together :). Any help appreciated.

PS: I plan to implement this in C# or MATLAB (depends on suitable method)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your file looks like a big CSV for that matlab has a good implementation with the Data Store

https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/what-is-a-datastore.html

And has this tools for working with large files:

https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/large-files-and-big-data.html

And also take a look to working [with tables in matlab](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html)

In your case you can work something like this:

the sample file airlinessmall.csv (123524 lines)

```
Year,Month,DayofMonth,DayOfWeek,DepTime,CRSDepTime,ArrTime,CRSArrTime,UniqueCarrier,FlightNum,TailNum,ActualElapsedTime,CRSElapsedTime,AirTime,ArrDelay,DepDelay,Origin,Dest,Distance,TaxiIn,TaxiOut,Cancelled,CancellationCode,Diverted,CarrierDelay,WeatherDelay,NASDelay,SecurityDelay,LateAircraftDelay
1987,10,21,3,642,630,735,727,PS,1503,NA,53,57,NA,8,12,LAX,SJC,308,NA,NA,0,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
1987,10,26,1,1021,1020,1124,1116,PS,1550,NA,63,56,NA,8,1,SJC,BUR,296,NA,NA,0,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
1987,10,23,5,2055,2035,2218,2157,PS,1589,NA,83,82,NA,21,20,SAN,SMF,480,NA,NA,0,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
1987,10,23,5,1332,1320,1431,1418,PS,1655,NA,59,58,NA,13,12,BUR,SJC,296,NA,NA,0,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
1987,10,22,4,629,630,746,742,PS,1702,NA,77,72,NA,4,-1,SMF,LAX,373,NA,NA,0,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
1987,10,28,3,1446,1343,1547,1448,PS,1729,NA,61,65,NA,59,63,LAX,SJC,308,NA,NA,0,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
1987,10,8,4,928,930,1052,1049,PS,1763,NA,84,79,NA,3,-2,SAN,SFO,447,NA,NA,0,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
1987,10,10,6,859,900,1134,1123,PS,1800,NA,155,143,NA,11,-1,SEA,LAX,954,NA,NA,0,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA

...
```

With data store tou can work with data as tables and get the variables you need, so for example to get de mean of the arrival delays:

```
>> ds = datastore('airlinesmall.csv','TreatAsMissing','NA');
>> ds.MissingValue = 0;
>> ds.SelectedVariableNames = 'ArrDelay';
>> data = preview(ds)

data = 

    ArrDelay
    ________

     8      
     8      
    21      
    13      
     4      
    59      
     3      
    11      

>> data % this is a table

data = 

    ArrDelay
    ________

     8      
     8      
    21      
    13      
     4      
    59      
     3      
    11      

>> sums = [];
counts = [];
while hasdata(ds)
    T = read(ds); % this is a table, but this is not all loaded in memory

    sums(end+1) = sum(T.ArrDelay);
    counts(end+1) = length(T.ArrDelay);
end

>> avgArrivalDelay = sum(sums)/sum(counts)

avgArrivalDelay =

    6.9670
```

Let's work with your sample. check this file:

sample.csv

```
TYPE OF FAILURE, START DATE, START TIME, DURATION, LOCALIZATION, WORKING TEAM, SHIFT
failure 1, 06/01/2017, 12/13/20, 300,  Area 1, A, morning
failure 2, 06/01/2017, 12/13/20, 300,  Area 1, A, night
failure 3, 06/01/2017, 12/13/20, 400,  Area 1, A, afternoon
failure 1, 08/01/2017, 12/13/20, 300,  Area 1, A, morning
failure 2, 09/01/2017, 12/13/20, 300,  Area 1, A, morning
failure 3, 09/01/2017, 12/13/20, 300,  Area 1, A, night
failure 3, 09/01/2017, 14/13/20, 200,  Area 1, A, morning
failure 1, 10/01/2017, 12/13/20, 300,  Area 1, A, morning
failure 1, 12/01/2017, 12/13/20, 300,  Area 1, A, afternoon
failure 2, 12/01/2017, 12/13/20, 500,  Area 1, A, morning
failure 1, 14/01/2017, 12/13/20, 300,  Area 1, A, night
```

You can see that failure 1 is every two days let's see this:

```
>> ds = tabularTextDatastore('sample.csv')
Warning: Variable names were modified to make them valid MATLAB identifiers. 

ds = 

  TabularTextDatastore with properties:

                      Files: {
                             '/home/anquegi/learn/matlab/stackoverflow/sample.csv'
                             }
               FileEncoding: 'UTF-8'
          ReadVariableNames: true
              VariableNames: {'TYPEOFFAILURE', 'STARTDATE', 'STARTTIME' ... and 4 more}

  Text Format Properties:
             NumHeaderLines: 0
                  Delimiter: ','
               RowDelimiter: '\r\n'
             TreatAsMissing: ''
               MissingValue: NaN

  Advanced Text Format Properties:
            TextscanFormats: {'%q', '%q', '%q' ... and 4 more}
         ExponentCharacters: 'eEdD'
               CommentStyle: ''
                 Whitespace: ' \b\t'
    MultipleDelimitersAsOne: false

  Properties that control the table returned by preview, read, readall:
      SelectedVariableNames: {'TYPEOFFAILURE', 'STARTDATE', 'STARTTIME' ... and 4 more}
            SelectedFormats: {'%q', '%q', '%q' ... and 4 more}
                   ReadSize: 20000 rows

>> ds.SelectedVariableNames = {'TYPEOFFAILURE', 'STARTDATE', 'STARTTIME', 'DURATION', 'LOCALIZATION', 'WORKINGTEAM', 'SHIFT'}

ds = 

  TabularTextDatastore with properties:

                      Files: {
                             '/home/anquegi/learn/matlab/stackoverflow/sample.csv'
                             }
               FileEncoding: 'UTF-8'
          ReadVariableNames: true
              VariableNames: {'TYPEOFFAILURE', 'STARTDATE', 'STARTTIME' ... and 4 more}

  Text Format Properties:
             NumHeaderLines: 0
                  Delimiter: ','
               RowDelimiter: '\r\n'
             TreatAsMissing: ''
               MissingValue: NaN

  Advanced Text Format Properties:
            TextscanFormats: {'%q', '%q', '%q' ... and 4 more}
         ExponentCharacters: 'eEdD'
               CommentStyle: ''
                 Whitespace: ' \b\t'
    MultipleDelimitersAsOne: false

  Properties that control the table returned by preview, read, readall:
      SelectedVariableNames: {'TYPEOFFAILURE', 'STARTDATE', 'STARTTIME' ... and 4 more}
            SelectedFormats: {'%q', '%q', '%q' ... and 4 more}
                   ReadSize: 20000 rows

>> reset(ds)
accum = [];
while hasdata(ds)
    T = read(ds);
    accum = datetime(T(strcmp(T.TYPEOFFAILURE,'failure 1'),:).STARTDATE, 'InputFormat','dd/MM/yyyy');
    mean(diff(accum))
end

ans = 

   48:00:00
```

% Exactly every 48 hours, and then you can try with every thing you want

Comment: Thank you for good hint :). I will definately look at Data Store for Matlab. However I was looking also for solving algorithmical part of my question. Can you tell me also something about that? :)

Comment: Of course I will give a try could you paste an example file, 5-6 lines and the example applied to that file

Comment: Edited to work with your sample data, if it helps do not forget to upvote or gift vcorrect answer